# Data sets for recommended nutrition with detailed information?

Tags: medical, food

While there is enough data which give a rough approximated nutrition information, if you dig deeper, you find that depending on a mineral or vitamin there can be big differences for the recommended intake depending on sex, age but also metabolism say for pregnant/lactating women.

Also as it seems there are dozens of known nutrients relevant for health.

Therefore, is there an up-to-date data set where all this data is compiled?